# DataError('value too long for type character varying(40) on Heroku but not on development

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, registration

My project works fine under the development but got this error on Heroku. The error occurs when user try to register. I use registration redux

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (value too long for type character varying(40)
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py", line 53, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\registration\views.py", line 56, in form_valid
    new_user = self.register(form)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\SaaS\sdg\sdgenv\users\views.py", line 44, in register
    new_user = super(Register, self).register(form_class)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\views.py", line 96, in register
    new_user = self.registration_profile.objects.create_inactive_user(
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py", line 185, in create_inactive_user
    registration_profile = self.create_profile(
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py", line 211, in create_profile
    profile.save()
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 198, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 133, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\sdgy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: value too long for type character varying(40)
```

I just made some updates including Python39 and Django 3. So maybe a lot have changed. But if the local environment is working fine, why does Heroku have issues?

My view

class Register(RegistrationView):
form_class = UserRegistrationForm

```
def register(self, form_class):

    new_user = super(Register, self).register(form_class)
    profile = Profile()
    profile.user = new_user
    profile.company = form_class.cleaned_data['company']
    profile.title = form_class.cleaned_data['title']
    profile.phone_number = form_class.cleaned_data['phone_number']
    profile.address = form_class.cleaned_data['address']
    profile.city = form_class.cleaned_data['city']
    profile.province = form_class.cleaned_data['province']
    profile.country = form_class.cleaned_data['country']
    profile.postal = form_class.cleaned_data['postal']
    profile.save()
    template = get_template('registration/registration.txt')

    context = {'name':new_user.first_name,'last':new_user.last_name,'company':profile.company,
                       'phone':profile.phone_number}

    content = template.render(context)

    return redirect('registration_complete')
```

My model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, max_length=250,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    province=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    postal=models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+6041234567'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True)  


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

I am learning here so please give me any pointers you might find helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether your database-migrations are identical on both, the Heroku and local DB?

Comment: Are you using sqlite locally? It's more permissive than other dbs and some constraints are not enforced.

Comment: biolomazur - yes I tried migrations on the heroku server too but no changes were detected.

Comment: 4140tm - I use postgres locally as well

Comment: bialomazur - You are correct. For some reason I can't just migrate with heroku server in the setting. I need to run the heroku command on the terminal to migrate.